# Tree Visualisation with Java

Tags: java, graph, tree

I am looking for a libary to generate Graphs or Trees like Organizations Charts.
This library should be able to generate plain Images from this graphs.

Does anyone knows a good, hopefully open source, library for Graph Visualization?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is probably your best bet.

It's an extremely powerful open-source graph visualization library.

Comment: If you're doing Swing, also take a look at the legacy version (JGraph5), some of its features are not yet supported in the new version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you know a good tutorial? I like to create a Org. Chart. But I found no way to create an auto aranged chart and how to save this as an Image.

Answer (score 5):

Graphstream Project looks incredible and is open source. The best about it, it's not Swing based:

[Graphstream Project](http://graphstream-project.org/)

[Github Link](https://github.com/graphstream)

```
Graph graph = new SingleGraph("Tutorial 1");
graph.setStrict(false);
graph.setAutoCreate(true); // optionally have it create nodes for you automatically
graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");
graph.display();
```

[image]

Or a tree:

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11782022)

Comment: Some example code would be nice.  The rule of thumb is: if the hyperlinks weren't there, would what remains be useful?  "Graphstream" is all you've really given us.  On the other hand, this type of question is not a good fit for SO, which is why it's now closed.

Comment: Oh I see. But if GraphStream / links would cease to exist any code snippet would be useless too.

Comment: Probably the worst thing you could pick if you just want a simple **tree** visualization tool. The documentation is extremely low-level, you have to put in a lot of effort to build something that even remotely. And I still have no idea how to actually visualize a *tree* properly with this, because by default it just visualizes it *randomly*.

Comment: Noone was talking about it having to be **simple**. You can disable the auto layouting and give nodes coordinates. This allows you to build a quick tree layouter (which is a textbook exercise). You can style anything through CSS like files, you're free to draw the tree how you want to and most importantly: You're not bound to Swing! (See edited post)
I agree about the docu though.

Comment: @Terran I'd love to see how you created the tree in your example, or which link you used. Even if it's textbook exercise, I'd prefer to just use a layout provided than implementing it all by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Check these libraries :

- [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)
- [jgraph](http://www.jgraph.com/)
- [jgrapht](http://www.jgrapht.org/)

Comment: jgrapht is not a visualization tool. It is a data structure for storing and doing some algorithms on it.